# tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits companies about arguments from documentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

So I have the following model that I am wanting to test out an idea with. I am particularly interested in [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits)  because my labels are not mutually exclusive.

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

w1 = tf.get_variable("w1", shape=[784, 512], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512], dtype=tf.float32))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([512, 10], dtype=tf.float32))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10], dtype=tf.float32))

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w1) + b1)
y = tf.matmul(h, w2) + b2

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    start = time.time()

    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

However, I am getting the following error repeatedly, which seems to be contradicting the tensor flow documentation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mnist_test.py", line 19, in <module>
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y)
TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  keyword argument `labels`  [only exists](https://web.archive.org/web/20170308155130/https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/issues/84) in TensorFlow 1.0.0 and above. I guess you're using 0.12 or below. Use `pip freeze` or `print('TensorFlow version: {0}'.format(tf.__version__))` to check.

---

The documentation for prior versions can be found at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/

To search for some information in the documentation of a previous version you can use: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12+sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()

Comment: Could someone provide a link to the old tensor flow documentation? I cannot find it on their website.

Comment: @JoshuaHoward added to the answer