# How to perform a multi label classification with tensorflow in purpose of auto tagging?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm new to tensorflow and would like to know if there is any tutorial or example of a multi-label classification with multiple network outputs.

I'm asking this because I have a collection of articles, in which, each article can have several tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, tensorflow supports *binary* multi-label classification via [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) loss function or the like (see the complete list in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47034888/712995)). If your tags are binary, in other words there's a predefined set of possible tags and each one can either be present or not, you can safely go with that. A single model to classify all labels at once. There are a lot of examples of such networks, e.g. one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42675391/712995).

Unfortunately, *multi-nomial* multi-label classification is not supported in tensorflow. If this is your case, you'd have to build a separate classifier for each label, each using [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) or a similar one.